# Cute File Browser - drag images to the desktop

Tags: javascript, php, web

Does anyone know how to configure Cute File Browser to allow images to be dragged to the desktop as its native file type as opposed to the URL?

Thank you - Matt

Comment: Yes, It is quite possible that someone has.  I am assuming that you did not intend to ask this yes or no question here.  Want to modify it?